# Как узнать количество символов в строке с кириллицей C++?

Tags: c++, строки, кириллица

```
int main() {
    string input;

    string s = "Пример!";
    cout << s.length();


    return 0;
}
```

У меня данный код выводит 13. Зависит от компилятора. Как я понял это из-за того, что кириллица занимает 2 байта. Можно ли как-то просто узнать количество символов не кастуя к массиву?

Comment: Тут все ещё хуже:) все ещё зависит от того, в какой кодировке это сохранено!

Comment: `Можно ли как-то просто узнать количество символов не кастуя к массиву?` А как узнать количество символов с помощью каста к массиву?

Comment: Посмотрите: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59691715/how-to-get-correct-length-of-stdu8string-in-c

Comment: А где тут кастинг к массиву?...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1212701/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-cout/1216803#1216803

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от множества деталей, но если ОС и компилятор вменяемые, то по-простому можно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

int main() {
  std::string s = "Пример!";

  // у меня пишет "7"
  std::cout << std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>,
                                    char32_t>{}.from_bytes(s).size() << '\n';
}
```

(они типа это deprecated в C++17, но заменить пока нечем, так что не удалят)

Comment: Если посмотреть на описание [utf-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), то легко сообразить, что `size_t len = 0; for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)     len += ((s[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80);` значительно эффективней

Answer (score -1):

Самый простой способ это пересчитать символы в цикле.

```
int main() {
    string input;
    
    string s = "Пример!";
    int i = 0;         // счетчик символов
    for (auto c : s)  // инкрементируем на каждом символе
    {
        i++;
    }
    cout << i;         // выводим результат
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А где Вы такой оригинальный образчик индусского кода нашли?

Comment: Я сам своего рода индус... но если что, нас учили в ВУЗ и более страшным вещам :)

Comment: Нашел в документации тот самый индийский код https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Там такого не вижу.

Comment: [Выводит 13](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e038b6e2922988e2).

Comment: А у меня выводит 7

Comment: В таком случае и `s.length()` у вас выведет `7`. В чём тогда преимущество вашего способа?